# How to give a property to an element using its title in css

Tags: html, css, properties

is it possible to give a property to an element using its title?

**example:**

```
 #id > a.class
```

**but the title instead of the id**

```
 "title" a.class
```

Comment: You mean the `title` attribute? If yes, use the attribute selectors `[title=value]`.

Comment: as mention already. in your css: [title='value'] https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see the code below:

```css
a[title="test"] {
 color : red;
}
```

```html
<a title="test" href="#">Test Link</a>
```